# Lock screen on Catalina has the wrong keyboard layout

Tags: login, catalina

After upgrading to Catalina the lock screen (the one that appears when the current session is locked by the user) has a different keyboard layout than the startup screen (the login screen that appears after I turn on my computer), and the rest of the system. When I enable the option to show the input menu on the menubar and login screen the keyboard layout is apparently the same, but that's not the case, because on the lock screen the password that I enter is not the right one even when I'm entering the right sequence of key strokes. What I have to do instead is to select the US layout and press the keys where those characters appear on the US layout. I tried enabling the virtual keyboard from the accessibility options to see where those keys are in the current layout but it only appears on the startup screen, the lock screen doesn't have a virtual keyboard.